# How Do I Implement an Async Call with Guzzle in PHP

Tags: php, guzzle

The code below does not work as expected: I thought it would be like Javascript where the browser is freed up. Having read around, I understand this is happening because PHP is single-threaded. However, the async functionality was included for a purpose so how is it meant to be used?

```
        $client = new Client();
        $response = $client->requestAsync('http://myurl');
        
        // there is a huge wait period here with browser unresponsive
        
        $response->then(function (Response $response) {
            echo $response->getBody();
        },
        function (RequestException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();  
        });
```

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by  ̀The code below does not work as expected`

Comment: In JS, between an Async call and “then”, you can continue other stuff in the browser. In guzzle/ php, code blocks for the whole operation. That’s no different from synchronous so why is this Async?

Comment: IMHO php being a server side language, as long as it doesn't send a response back to the browser, the latter will be frozen. The fact that you're making an async request with Guzzle allow you to do other stuff waiting for the request response but only in the backend. If you're looking for an async request without freezing the browser you may try triggering it directly from javascript in the browser.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, makes sense.

Comment: You're welcome. I'll make it an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP being a server side language, as long as it doesn't send a response back to the browser, the latter will be frozen. The fact that you're making an async request with Guzzle allow you to do other stuff waiting for the request response but only in the backend. If you're looking for an async request without freezing the browser you may try triggering it directly from javascript in the browser.